# Git commands in WSL sometimes fails to resolve the URLs

Tags: git, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, resolve

WSL in my windows10 machine sometimes fails to resolve some URLs.

Observed that the issue occurred while executing git commands. Mainly the commands like:

```
git pull --ff-only
git push
```

It fails to pull from github.com, and go.googlesource.com. But the ping works correctly:

```
ping go.googlesource.com
```

It also fails when pushing to Azure DevOps(via ssh).
The error shows:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.dev.azure.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Important:**

This problem occurs only sometimes. When a git push attempt to azure devops fails, after 2-3 retries, 4th time the push succeeds.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using an non-Microsoft antivirus or firewall, and if so, does removing it completely and restarting work?  Some third-party antivirus software breaks WSL.

Comment: @bk2204 No, there are no third-party antivirus softwares installed in the machine.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I get something similar.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I had the same issue due to being connected to my company VPN, just disconnecting from it and it worked